# Htaccess optional trailing slash when associating extensionless url with php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use the following rule to associate extensionless url with php file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I would like to change that to work no matter the ending trailing slash.

```
^([^\.]+)/$
```

Works with /example/

```
^([^\.]+)$
```

Works with /example

```
^([^\.]+)/?$
```

Tried with that one where slash is optional but not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ^([^\.]+)/?$
> ```

This won't work as intended because regex is "greedy" by default, so the captured pattern consumes the trailing slash since it is *optional* at the end of the URL-path. In other words, a request for `/foo/` ends up being rewritten to `foo/.php`, not `foo.php` as intended.

You need to make the captured group non-greedy, by using `+?` instead of `+`.

For example:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

In addition...

- The `NC` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive was superfluous.
- No need to escape a literal dot in a character class.
- You should ensure that `MultiViews` is disabled (to avoid potential conflicts in the future, if not already.)

---

*Aside:* However, by making both `/foo/` and `/foo` resolve to the same page you are potentially creating a canonicalisation issue / duplicate content. You should decide which is the canonical and *externally redirect* one to the other.